# How to reason with the $d\mu$ term in Lebesgue integration?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppse $f:\Omega \rightarrow \hat{\Omega}$. 
We define measure $\hat P$ in the following way.  $$\hat{P}(A)=P(f^{-1}(A))$$ for $A\subset\hat\Omega$.

How do we derive a formula for $\int_{\Omega} g(f(\omega))dP$ **informally** by manipulating the symbols $dP$ and $d\hat{P}$?

I.e is there a way to write $d\hat P = dP(f^{-1})$ and go from there to derive a formula? (I know the result and the formal proof. Looking for an informal one here to help with calculation. )

EDIT:

The answer is $\int_{\hat \Omega} g d\hat P$.

Comment: You should put the final answer in since it would be useful for some people in providing a loose proof.

Comment: In other words, you are looking for an *intuition* about [pushforward measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure)?

Comment: @XanderHenderson That is exactly it. Can you put it in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using the duality "pushforward-pullback". Let $g\colon \Omega_1\to\Omega_2$ be a measurable transformation and suppose that $P$ is a measure on $\Omega_1$.

The pullback of the function $f$ by the function $g$ is 
$$
g^\star f(x)=f(g(x)), $$ 
while the pushforward of the measure $P$ by the function $g$ is 
$$
g_\star P(A)=P(g^{-1}(A)).$$

This notation is useful because it immediately suggests the duality formula 
$$
\int_{\Omega_2} f(y)g_{\star}(dP)(y)=\int_{\Omega_1} g^\star f(x)\, dP(x).$$

**EDIT**. As discussed in comments to Xander's answer, the pushforward measure $g_\star(dP)$ is nothing more than a notation, to denote "the measure you obtain by imposing the change of variable $y=g(x)$". That's nothing deep behind this definition.

Answer (score 0):

The measure that you are asking about is a [pushforward measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure).  Pushforward measures are used to generalize the baby-calculus change of variables formulae to spaces that are more interesting than $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the pushforward measures *generalize* the change of variable formula. Rather, a pushforward measure is just a *notation* to denote the measure that one obtains by change of variable.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Notice that I didn't claim that it generalized the change of variables formula, but that it generalizes the *baby-calculus* change of variables formula, which is the version see in introductory calculus classes, and is generally seen as a tool for dealing with Riemann integrals.  Pushforward measures generalize that notion.

Comment: I see your point. Anyway, I added a small edit to my answer to clarify what I wanted to say.